# Why is python skipping these lines of code?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to draw some pygame circles and display them and when the user hits a key it updates the position of these counters. When the user hits the key it will draw a circle on the screen in  a new position but it doesn't display the first image. So it should display a circle and when they hit a key it changes the position of the circle. It doesn't draw the starter circle.

First circles(These don't appear):

```
#Draw counters using pygame draw line function. These are the default counters on the start position. These don't move.
    countY = 750
    count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(150, countY), 25, 0)
    count2 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(250, countY), 25, 0)
    count3 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(450, countY), 25, 0)
    count4 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 255),(550, countY), 25, 0)
    print("Should draw start counters")
    pygame.display.update()
```

Circles drawn after key entered:

```
while game:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        pygame.event.get()

        #Counter 1 movement
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
            diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)

            window.fill(grey)
            grid()

            count1 = pygame.draw.circle(window, (black),(150, countY - 72 * diceRoll), 25, 0)
```

Comment: Maybe you need to include more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a key is pressed, you fill the background surface with grey:

```
if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
    diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)

    window.fill(grey) # <--- fills the entire surface with a solid color!
```

and you don't draw the circles again.

An easy fix is to keep a list of all circles, and draw them every frame (there are more efficient approaches, but let's keep it simple for the sake of this question/answer).

```
circles = []
countY = 750
circles.append((pygame.color.Color('black'), (150, countY), 25, 0))
circles.append((pygame.color.Color('black'), (250, countY), 25, 0))
circles.append((pygame.color.Color('white'), (450, countY), 25, 0))
circles.append((pygame.color.Color('white'), (550, countY), 25, 0))

while game:
    window.fill(grey)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # pygame.event.get() don't call pygame.event.get() twice

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_a:
            diceRoll = random.randint(1, 4)
            circles.append((pygame.color.Color('black'), (150, countY - 72 * diceRoll), 25, 0))

    for (color, pos, rad, w) in circles:
        pygame.draw.circle(window, color, pos, rad, w)
    pygame.display.flip()
```